# how to create facebook auth dialog preview user

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-test-users

I'm using open graph to publish actions on users' feed. My tests are ok for admin users and now I want to test it on "Auth dialog preview user"'s timeline before submiting any approuval. But I can't see this user anywhere. So I tried to create him by using:
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=Auth+Dialog+Preview+User&locale=en_US&permissions=APP_PERMISSIONS&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN. It was created successfully but when I try to publish action on it's timeline I got the error message: "Application with ID has not been granted the capability to use the property message". So I understand that the user I created is not recognized as a test user. Is there any way to have a valid one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do it by app dashboard? `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APP_ID>/roles` at the bottom there is section like "Test users" and link "Add".

Comment: Yes, I've already tried adding it by app dashboard, the result is the same: Application with ID has not been granted the capability to use the property message

Answer (score 1):

If the actions are created but the user is not there, click "Get Code" as described from this section

> The first thing you should do is create an Open Graph Action, by
>   clicking the Open Graph link as shown in the above image
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOURAPPID/opengraph Set your
>   namespace because we need this to define your Open Graph meta data as
>   stated in the protocol – http://ogp.me
>
> Next, go back to the Open Graph link and create an action
>
> - Plan a Trip
> - Walk the dog
> - Drink Computers
>
> Honestly, the actual action isn’t important right now. All I am trying
>   to do is lead you to the Auth Preview User, it will be up to you to
>   make the next steps.
>
> Once that’s set, go to the Open Graph Dashboard.
>
> [image: Open Graph Dashboard]
>
> Select “Get Code” this should return a cURL command for you to execute
>
> ```
> curl -F 'access_token=xxx' \
>      -F 'computer=http://samples.ogp.me/465737726804711' \
>         'https://graph.facebook.com/me/@_@:drink'
> ```
>
> You don’t need to execute the cURL command, just go to your roles,
>   that Auth Dialog Preview User should be looking at you with his white
>   avatar self.
>
> > Help! I’ve deleted the Auth Dialog Preview User and I cannot get him back :( Thanks in advance. This is urgent
>
> Well adding him back via Roles isn’t going to work, so what are you
>   going to do?
>
> Click Get Code again on your Open Graph action, this should bring the
>   Auth Dialog Preview User back again.

If that doesn't work execute the cURL command as shown above and see how that works.

<sub>Source: http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/summoning-the-auth-dialog-preview-user/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> now I want to test it on "Auth dialog preview user"'s timeline before submiting any approuval. But I can't see this user anywhere.

If you have Open Graph actions for your app set up already, you should find the Auth dialog preview user on the *roles* tab in your app settings.

It’s created automatically, you do not do that yourself.

Comment: That's what I expected, but It's not created

Answer (score 0):

You will get more details about
1.Authentication
2.Auth dialog
from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but my auth dialog configuration is already set up. The test user that I created have accepted all permissions of my app (ie publish_stream, read_stream, email...). My problem is that my test user is not recognized as test user

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get test user "Auth Dialog Preview User" created. I didn't have this user on my test users on the dashbord, so I submitted an approuval with this status. Of course, my request was rejected but fortunately, the user was created at the same time. I just do my test on its timeline and resubmit an approuval. Now every thing is ok. Thank you for all